# Must Declare a scalar variable @Code

Tags: c#

Why it is asking for declaring a scalar variable @Code

```
private DataSet SearchRecord ( string lQuery, string SwiftCode) 
    using ( pConnectionState = new SqlConnection(pConnectionString) )
    {
        try
        {
            string TableName = "ACCOUNT_DETAILS";
            pConnectionState.Open();
            SqlCommand lSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(lQuery , pConnectionState);
            lSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SwiftCode" , SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SwiftCode;
            SqlDataAdapter lSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(lQuery, pConnectionState);
            DataTable lDataTable = new DataTable(TableName);
            DataSet lDataSet = new DataSet();
            lSqlDataAdapter.Fill(lDataSet, TableName);
            pConnectionState.Close();
            return lDataSet;     
        }
        catch (  Exception ex )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: not an answer to your question but I recommend using lSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue

Comment: Also not answer, but 'pConnectionState.Close();' is redundant when you are 'using'.

Comment: check the value you pass in lQuery. You may have "@Code" in the SQL instead of "@SwiftCode" (or in addition to it)

Comment: Can u plz tell me what is the value of lQuery? beocz In lQuery there is something which is relate to @Code.

Comment: Serve Laurijssen: I did tried lSqlCommand.Parametes.AddWithValue :(

Comment: Paolo Falabella: I did updated my query to "@SwiftCode" instead of "@Code"

The updated query looks like this:
                lQuery = "SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE SWIFT_CODE = @SwiftCode ";

Comment: Heslacher: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of not seeing the wood for the trees:

You are building your **SqlCommand lSqlCommand** just fine ( now after replacing the @Code with @SwiftCode ), **but you are never using it**. Instead you create a **SqlDataAdapter lSqlDataAdapter** by using the constructror which takes the command text and the connection object, **missing your parameters at all**.

You just need to create your SqlDataAdapter like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter lSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(lSqlCommand);
```

and your query will run like it should.